# Eclipse project into mercurial

Tags: java, android, mercurial

I'm sorry about this question but I'm very new in mercurial, I have an android project in eclipse already created and working and a web repository at bitbucket.org, I created a repository but I can't share the project into that repository. It must be something fool what I'm doing, but I don't know what is it. Please any help is very welcome

Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't give much information on what exactly the problem is. You need to do following steps:

1. Right click on the project, choose Team > Share Project and then select Mercurial and click Next.
2. The dialog will offer to create a repository in the project location. Click Finish to do that.
3. Again right click on the project and choose Team > Commit. Enter a commit message and check that all files you want to include are checked in the list. Click OK.
4. One more time right click on the project and choose Team > Push.
5. The the dialog enter the URL of your Bitbucket repository and the login. Click Finish.

Now your code should be in the Bitbucket repository.

To send more changes to Bitbucket, you repeat steps 3, 4 and 5.

If you have a problem, you'll need to exactly explain which step isn't working and what exactly is wrong.